# instagram App Permissions Denied

Tags: permissions, instagram, instagram-api

We have an app and have built in IG integration but keep getting denied on our submission.  We want to allow our users who have IG accounts to sign in on our app and then link their IG account.  We show the IG icon and their IG name with a follow button so a user can gain followers on IG through our app.  We need the follower list permission so that we can know if they are already following them or not and the relationship permission so that we can follow from our app.  We have detailed the use case demo'd on a video but this is the only reply we continue to get.  Any assistance would be great.

follower_list:
This permission (follower_list) does not support the use case you described in your submission notes, screencast and website. Please review Login Permissions (http://instagram.com/developer/authorization/) for a comprehensive list of permissions and valid use cases.

relationships:
This permission (relationships) does not support the use case you described in your submission notes, screencast and website. Please review Login Permissions (http://instagram.com/developer/authorization/) for a comprehensive list of permissions and valid use cases.

Comment: This is not really a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue with them declining my application for a valid use case.

I think it's because there wasn't enough information for them to validate the app, or the website isn't following their [Platform Policy](https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/). I would read through it and make sure you're doing everything they want you to do. I would triple check what use case you picked and how you justified that your app falls into it.

It's also good to cover these, taken from Instagram.com:

> Your submission should explain what does your app or company do, which
>   of the approved use cases your integration falls into, who will be
>   using your app, how do your user authenticate with your app, how you
>   use the API to power your integration, how does your product use the
>   data acquired from Instagram, etc.